# How to plot incomplete series with highchart

Tags: highcharts, linechart

I have a monthly series that starts at 1st and finishes at last day 30th or 31th. The problem is for the current month, I don't have all days do plot but I would like to show all days without the point like this image:

![Exemple of chart I would like to produce][1]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/eSuTR.jpg

Is there any option in highchart to make this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the [`xAxis.max`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.max) to a value. Something like:

```
$(function () {     $('#container').highcharts({
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'],
            max: 11
        },
        series: [{
            data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4]        
        }]  }); });
```